# Passing properties with variable names to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which generates a variable number of elements, all with different names, like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Model.NumRubbers; i++)
{
    ... some code
    for (int j = 1; j < Model.NumSetsInRubbers; j++)
    {
      <input type="number" min="0" size="3" maxlength="3" 
             class="number  homescore scoreinput form-control"
             name="match_@i-homeset_@j"
             id="match_@i-homeset_@j"/>
```

So as you can see there will be an indeterminate number of elements created with variable names.  How should I construct my input class in the controller in order to save these values?

Comment: how does your input Model class look like now?

Comment: Why are you not generating your controls correctly so that your bind to your model. Show you model(s). Using `FormCollection` is a dreadful anti-MVC way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't try to create a request model in this case but rather rely on the `FormCollection` argument.

```
public ActionResult Foo (FormCollection form)
{
    // to get values out of the collection, use the indexer property
    var foo = form["match_1-homeset_2"];
}
```

You probably aren't going to want to hard-code the value as the example shows, more likely you'll do a nested loop on the server side to process the data.

Comment: I didn't know about the formcollection class. Have tested this and it works perfectly, I'll just make a nested loop like in the view to get the results. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to handle the creation of your object in the model itself and then use EditorFor templates for the various parts of your model. This will allow for simpler code and also SOC across your view parts.

SomeModel.cs

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public List<SomeOtherType> NumSetsInRubbers { get; set; }
    public SomeModel(int numRubbers, int numSetsInRubbers)
    {
        // this is just a flimsy example to show how you can create a list of nodes. Notet hat you could nest nodes in other node types but it was hard to gleam from your example how you actually had the code setup
        this.NumSetsInRubbers = new List<SomeOtherType>(numRubbers*numSetsInRubbers);
        for(int i = 0; i < NumSetsInRubbers.Count; i++)
            NumSetsInRubbers[i] = new SomeOtherType();
    }
}

public class SomeOtherType
{
    public int Match { get; set; }
}
```

#### View

You should then use an Editor template for `SomeOtherType`

**EditorTemplates\SomeOtherType.cshtml**

```
@model SomeOtherType

@Html.InputFor(x => x.Match)
```

**Your original template** - this then calls though to the editor template above

```
@model SomeModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NumSetsInRubbers)
```

In your view code you have a nested object, you can duplicate this behavior as well if you have a containing type which then has another type. You can just continue to call (chain) EditorFor in your templates. The EditorFor handles the collection and adds a view instance for each item in the collection.

Comment: thanks for your contribution, this looks great, but I've already implemented Craig's formcollection and it works fine so I'll stick with that.

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript to iterate over your collection of inputs and build an object to send to your controller with AJAX.

Comment: question was about Model for this view, not about how to send it

Comment: The question literally does not even include the word 'Model' but anyway, I take it to mean that the OP needs to get some data to a controller, and this is one way to do that.

Comment: OP asks *how to contruct input class for controller*

Comment: No doubt this would work, but Craig's answer seems quicker and easier, thanks anyway.

Comment: It depends which language you are most comfortable with really. At one end or the other you will assign values from the form to an object. Glad you've found a solution anyway :)